# Remove Select Photos... option on PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization

Tags: ios, swift, permissions, photo, ios14

How can I remove the `Select Photos...` option when requesting for access permission in photo library?

I use PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization to create a access request and it shows me this.

[image: photo album imaage]

I want to remove the `Select Photos...` option because the function of this feature is to save a image in a custom photo album.

This is my code for performing a permission request.

```swift
if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() != PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
    PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ (status: PHAuthorizationStatus) in
         // save depending on status
    })
} else {
    // save image
}
```

Comment: Any update on this ? I want to achieve the same thing but couldn't do it. I tried using PHPhotoLibraryPreventAutomaticLimitedAccessAlert = YES. but no success.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the  Select Photos... option from permission pop-up. and even PHPhotoLibraryPreventAutomaticLimitedAccessAlert = YES won't help